google login with unity and Firebase in window platform
how can i do google login?
As i know, GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential method needs Idtoken that generated when user login in web browser.
But in unity Window Platform, i can't get url from web brower with Application.OpenURL() method.
With Unity using Window Platform and Firebase, how can i support google social login for user?
private const string authorizationEndpoint_second = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
private const string new_redirectUri = "https://haxxxxn.xxxxxx.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler"; 
private const string clientId_second = "10497xxxxxx-hfxxxxxxxxxx8.apps.googleusercontent.com"; 
private const string scope_second = "email profile"; 

void Start()
    {
        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.Result == DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Could not resolve Firebase dependencies: " + task.Exception);
                return;
            }
        });
    }

IEnumerator OpenOAuthURL()
    {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;

        var credential = GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

        var authUrl_second = $"{authorizationEndpoint_second}?response_type=code&client_id={clientId_second}&redirect_uri={new_redirectUri}&scope={scope_second}";

        Application.OpenURL(authUrl_second);

        while (!Application.absoluteURL.StartsWith(new_redirectUri))
        {
            credential = GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }

        //get authCode by parsing url now accessing
        string authCode = GetAuthCodeFromUrl(Application.absoluteURL);
    }


Tried Application.OpenURL() method. But i can't get idtoken.
Using webview to get url. But i can't get url and set authentication url.
Google Sign-in SDK is useless in Window Platform.
